# vim search for underscored variable name with *

Tags: vim, vi

When I press `*` on a variable name such as `hello`, 
vim will highlight names like `this->hello` or `this.hello`, but not `_hello`.

It is a very strange behavior because I can highlight all `hello`'s by `/hello`.
But for some reason, `*` behaves differently from `/`.

Is there any way to make `*` to highlight all `hello`'s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `*` key it effectively searches for

```
\<theword\>
```

The surrounding `\<...\>` means that it only looks for whole words.  So `bhello` would not be found, in your example.

You can modify the characters that are counted as non-keyword values by `set iskeyword`

The default (in my version) is

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

So we can ensure `_` is not part of this:

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,192-255,^_
```

This can be put in your `.vimrc` file or run with a `:set` inside `vim`

Comment: `iskeyword` is normally set from `fptlugin`s, and some syntax files also mess with it.  This is obvious if you think about it for a moment, since it has to be in synch with the current `filetype`.  Consequently, (1) there is no "one true `iskeyword`" but many, and (2) if you ever want to override it you have to do it from an `after/ftplugin`, otherwise your override will be ignored.

Comment: Or run `:set isk-=_`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `g*` command instead of `*`:

```
g*          Like "*", but don't put "\<" and "\>" around the word.
            This makes the search also find matches that are not a
            whole word.
```